# Sorting org-mode org-agenda file

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, sorting

I have an org-mode file in standard agenda format:

```
* Dentist
<2015-10-01>
* Put up shelves
<2015-10-05>
```

I'm just starting to use org-agenda but I still use just that single file a lot just as an regular org-mode fully-expanded tree, and it's handy to have it kept sorted in date order.

Currently I sort it by hand.  How can I get emacs to sort it by date?

Comment: Here is an advanced example of programmatically sorting by multiple criteria the main org-mode buffer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489  I sort automatically with a prompt yes/new each time I open my master calendar org-mode file, and whenever I add a new task/event, or whenever I modify an existing task/event, except a few circumstances where I don't want to see it moving around until I call a programmatic sort interactively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select the entire buffer and do <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> (it runs the command `org-sort`). It will prompt you for the `type` of sorting.

To understand different types of sorting see the documentation of `org-sort-entries` (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`org-sort-entries`<kbd>RET</kbd>). I am quoting it here for completeness

> Sort entries on a certain level of an outline tree.
>   If there is an active region, the entries in the region are sorted.
>   Else, if the cursor is before the first entry, sort the top-level items.
>   Else, the children of the entry at point are sorted.
>
> Sorting can be alphabetically, numerically, by date/time as given by
>   a time stamp, by a property, by priority order, or by a custom function.
>
> The command prompts for the sorting type unless it has been given to the
>   function through the SORTING-TYPE argument, which needs to be a character,
>   (?n ?N ?a ?A ?t ?T ?s ?S ?d ?D ?p ?P ?o ?O ?r ?R ?f ?F ?k ?K).  Here is
>   the precise meaning of each character:
>
> a   Alphabetically, ignoring the TODO keyword and the priority, if any.
>
> c   By creation time, which is assumed to be the first inactive time stamp
>       at the beginning of a line.
>
> d   By deadline date/time.
>
> k   By clocking time.
>
> n   Numerically, by converting the beginning of the entry/item to a number.
>
> o   By order of TODO keywords.
>
> p   By priority according to the cookie.
>
> r   By the value of a property.
>
> s   By scheduled date/time.
>
> t   By date/time, either the first active time stamp in the entry, or, if
>       none exist, by the first inactive one.
>
> Capital letters will reverse the sort order.

Comment: What took me much time to understand is that sorting by multiple criteria can be accomplished programmatically by running `org-sort-entries` several times in a row with different sorts -- e.g., `(org-sort-entries t ?a) (org-sort-entries t ?o) (org-sort-entries t ?p) (org-sort-entries t ?t)`